# in mongo get rankings using aggregation or map reduce

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

So I need to get rank and total in a catgory for a a user's posts in my database.  For example the desired output could be

```
Hi bob, here are your posts rankings:  
 'Breaking News' is ranked #10 of 203 in the 'news' category
 'Day at the Game' is ranked #24 of 67 in the 'sports' category".
```

And here is the Schema

```
PostSchema = new Schema({
 {
  score:Number,
  categoryId: ObjectId,
  categoryName: String,
  title: String,
  username: String
 }
});
```

Sample Post

```
{ score: 12, 
  categoryId:"50cf7d2841d41f4f35000000", 
  categoryName:"sports", 
  title:"Day at the Game", 
  username:"bob"
}
```

I suppose I can try this in map reduce but is there a way using the aggregation commands?  What would be the most efficient map reduce function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a difficult one.

What you are most likely trying to do is the same as many sites such as this one (stackoverflow) do with top answers and askers in a tag (i.e. `mongodb`) but on a per user level.

You can see an example of what I meant just now here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mongodb/topusers

The problem with the aggregation framework and/or map reduce is that you must calculate the stats for ALL records under that category for ALL users. This might OK for 203 records but when you start reaching possibly thousands it will get very hard to do this in realtime.

That is why it is normally better to do this, just like other sites (including this one), once a day maybe via map reduce.

I must admit I know of no way to do this with the aggregation framework since each pipe iteration cannot store constants about its previous iteration (i.e. an incremental figure) unless it is on one of the group operators.

However the points I have raised here should help you understand whether you are actually going down the right path here.